# Regexp for checking if number is above 10

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

Need to check if given number is above 10. With regular expression. Not with pl.
Number is positive integer without leading zeroes and without plus sign in a string format.
This code neeeded for replacing quantities above 10 with '10+'

Tested two answers with 1 mil runs on same numbers:

`^(?!10$)[1-9]\d+$` - 5.373779535293579 sec

`^(?:1[1-9]|[2-9]\d|\d{3,})$` - 1.5149388313293457 sec

Comment: By number do you mean integer, fractional or scientific notation?

Comment: And for sure would be good to show us some of your efforts

Comment: The regular expressions are a powerful tool but they cannot solve all problems in the world. Even if your problem could be solved using a regular expression, the effort to produce the solution and to understand the solution when one reads it later is not worth the benefit. It is much easier both for the code writer and for its readers to keep it simple. Use a regular expression to validate that the string contains only digits (and an optional `-` in front, if negative numbers are allowed) then parse the string using a function provided by the language and compare the number with `10`.

Comment: You could use a [neg. lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): [`^(?!10$)[1-9]\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/2N6jzp/1) - Usually I'd avoid lookarounds if it can be done without but in this case it's somehow easier to read, shorter and not less efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a simple enough matter:

```
^(?:1[1-9]|[2-9]\d|\d{3,})$
```

Comment: I see you split numbers on three groups:
11-19, 20-99, and 100+.
Quite nice!
The only question, does regexp provide shorter solution, or this one is quintessential?

Comment: The only other way to do it is by negating it and using negative look-behind. Something like `.*(?<!^\d)(?<!^10)$`. I just tend to avoid them because if there is one extended regex feature that a library might not implement, it's negative look-behind -- case in point, Safari. Also the match is very ...inside out and backwards. Definitely doable though, if you prefer it!

Comment: Also the matching negative lookahead, of course. They are interchangeable. The guy above gave that solution in a comment. It has the same (possible) limitations, however.